# Get a variable name from database

Tags: php, database, variables

I'm a little confused - how do I get a variable name stored to a database?!
Record in the database is a string: `"$test"`

The variable $user is set before the records a fetched from database. So I want to "convert" this string to a real variable to get the value of it.

The following didn't work:

```
// $test is set to 'bla'
$test = 'bla';
// $var is the value from the database
$var = '$test';
// print $test
echo ${$var};
```

I know that it would work if I remove the '$' from the database record

```
$var = 'test';
echo $$var;
```

But how to handle this without?

Comment: You could remove the $ via string replace, but I question why you are even doing this?

Comment: There is no need to put `{}` with a variable, you can just do this `echo $var;`

Comment: But `echo $var;` will give me only the string `"$test"`. Not the value of the variable `$test`.

Comment: If you want to echo the value that is put in the variable $test, please use `echo $test;`  (without quotes, or double quotes).   If `test` refers to a database column name, you first need to fetch the right record from the database with an SQL statement, put the results in a variable and then echo the contents of the variable,  if you want to see it.  But I suggest you do some reading up on PHP first...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String replace in better option, if you don't want to replace `$` you can use `eval` function:

```
$test = 'bla';
$var = '$test';

eval("\$var = \"$var\";");

echo $var; //output: bla
```

Comment: That's it. I tried it with `eval()` but a little different - without success. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar problem just now.
Here is what I did:
$res[0] is obtained from mysql_fetch_array() and it contains another query which has $variable embedded.

```
$qry="select query from sql_list where id=".$sql_id;
$result=mysql_query($qry);
$res=mysql_fetch_array($result);
eval("\$qry_2 = \"$res[0]\";");
mysql_query($qry_2)
```

It works! Maybe someone can suggest a better way.

Answer (score 0):

This is 3 years later but since no one give you your answer, maybe this will help you or the next person searching for this.

From what I understand, you already declared a variable and stored the name of that `var` in the db.

```
$var = '$test'; // from db
$var[0] = ''; // remove first letter, simple & much faster than ( trim or substr )

//content of var
$var_content = ${$var};
```